# Why does component not show correct values on screen when inside xhr readyState and status check

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Below is a really stripped back example showing the issue.

Basically the first commented out for loop would display '0 1 2 3 4' on the screen, however, the same code simply within the readystate/status check doesn't display anything on the screen (yet if you console log the array you can see all the right data in there)

What am I missing?

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const Results = props => {
    const Posts = []

    const Post = props => {
        return <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    }

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("THIS LOGS FINE IN CONSOLE")
        // DOES DISPLAY VALUES IN BROWSER
        // for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        //     Posts.push(<Post key={i} title={i} />)
        // }

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("THIS LOGS FINE AS WELL IN CONSOLE")
            // DOES *NOT* DISPLAY VALUES IN BROWSER
            for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                Posts.push(<Post key={i} title={i} />)
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "/index.json")
    xhr.send()

    return (
        <>
            <Layout>
                <SEO title="Search" />
                <ul data-results className="flex flex-wrap mx-auto">
                    {Posts}
                </ul>
            </Layout>
        </>
    )
}

export default Results
```

Comment: Is this a local json file? Any reason not to just use `gatsby-transformer-json`?

Answer (score 1):

`Posts` should be a part of the State of this React component.
By the time `onreadystatechange`is called, `Posts` is no longer a thing that React is watching to determine whether or not this component re-renders or not. If you use `setState` to update `Posts` (that should be a part of the State), then React will re-render.

I would read the documentation on State from the [Official React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)